# Grails MS SQLServer 2008 jdbc driver causes problems in tomcat

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, grails

What is the official way to use the microsoft jdbc driver for mssql in a grails application?
The general opinion that I found through googling is that I only have to drop the jar in the lib directory of the grails app. This works if I do a grails clean and grails compile --refresh-dependencies. But when I deploy on a real server I have two problems.

When redeploying there is this a warning in the logs.

> 24.05.2013 16:03:03 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI 
>   WARNUNG: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

I'm not sure if its something to care about since its a warning. But I would like to have my logs clean and I have the dll in the lib directory of the application just as google is saying. Additionally on redeployment there are several messages like this that might relate to the first one:

> 24.05.2013 16:03:02 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
>   SCHWERWIEGEND: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.MyThreadLocal] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$MyThreadLocal@76fe8d1b]) and a value of type [null] (value [null]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.

And the last thing is that my coworker said, that she thinks the driver should not be installed on a per application basis but directly into tomcat. I actually don't know how to do this, but if I did it, this would cause a problem on the development machine since I don't know how to get grails run-app going without the driver in the applications lib directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still place the library in the `lib` folder of your project and just exclude this from the war generation.

You don't need to exclude the jar everytime you build your project, just [follow this post tip](http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2009/01/21/excluding-files-from-a-war-with-grails-the-right-way/).

In your Tomcat server the jar will be placed in the shared lib folder instead of each web application.

If after that you still get the warning about `sqljdbc_auth.dll` you will need to locate this file and add the folder in the Tomcat classpath (or copy to Tomcat lib folder).